# How to add application to Azure AD using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent for creating resources in Azure programmatically. The package requires me to create an Azure AD Application which will be used by my console app to authenticate for the resource management api. So far so good - I created that AD app and use that in my console app, "normal" resource management is working fine.

Now I wanted to start to also programmatically create other Azure AD Applications using the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent package, which is a direct dependency of the package mentioned above. While I can use the package e.g. for listing existing Azure AD Applications, I am getting authorization issues (401) as soon as I try to create new Azure AD applications with it. I tried playing around with the permissions I gave to the AD app used by the console app, but had no success.

Is there either a way to...

1. give an Azure AD Application permission to create other Azure AD Applications (this is my preferred way), and if so, which are the permissions required?
2. or to use the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package with an actual "human" user account that has the permissions required to create Azure AD Applications?

Answer (score 1):

The https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent package uses Azure AD Graph to create the application.

And there is no such app-only permission that we can create the application. As a alternative way we can grant the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission for the Windows Azure Active Directory and the sign-in user with Global Admin for that tenant. Here is a figure which grant the specific permission for your reference:
[image]

### Update

This library which using the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant** is designed for the **native client application**.

In this scenario, you can register an native client app which is public app that there is no secret. Or you can perform the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow** using the `HttpClient` class. Here is a piece of code for your reference:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string body = String.Format("resource={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&grant_type=password&username={3}&password={4}", Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net"), "{clientId}", Uri.EscapeDataString("{client_secret}"), Uri.EscapeDataString("{userName}"), Uri.EscapeDataString("{password}"));
StringContent sc = new StringContent(body,Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var resoult= client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token", sc).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;          

Console.WriteLine(resoult);
```

In addition, since the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant** flow use the users' username/password to authentication, please ensure that the you trust the client which run this app( refer [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in this case, I'd use 

AzureCredentials.FromUser("my-user-name", "my-password", "the-client-id-of-the-ad-app", "my-tenant-id", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)

to create the azure credentials used to create the GraphRbacManagementClient? Where would I need to put the AD apps client secret in this case?

Comment: You can use a native client app which doesn't require the secret to use this flow to acquire the token. I have update my post please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - i will probably not be able to test this in the next days, but I will let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: @Schweder Is the issue was fixed? Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.